# Browser Crashes in Page Retrieving Loop, Python Selenium Script

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I wrote this simple script - it simply fetches an image from blogposts and posts it to Pinterest. It works great, except that after about 43 pages, the browser hangs/freezes.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of "leak" causing things to get out of control? Perhaps there is something I can alter in the script to make it run without crashing?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pickle
import os.path

import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#START THE RACE

driver.get("https://www.pinterest.com/login/")
assert "Pinterest" in driver.title

#name
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username_or_email")
elem.send_keys("someone@something.com")

#pass
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
elem.send_keys("12345")

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

new_url = 'something.com/something_else'
driver.get(new_url)
i=0

while(1):
    i=i+1
    print i

    time.sleep(5)

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pin-it-btn-wrapper a").click();

    time.sleep(3)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-pin-index="0"]').click();
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#prev_post a").click();

    time.sleep(3)

    handles = driver.window_handles

    if(handles):
        for handle in handles:
            driver.switch_to_window(handle)
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.pinIt').click();                
                time.sleep(2)

            except:
                continue

    time.sleep(3) 

    if(handles):
        for handle in handles:
            driver.switch_to_window(handle)
            try:
                time.sleep(1)    
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#prev_post a").click();
                time.sleep(3)
                break
            except:
                continue   


#assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
#driver.close()
```

The script itself logs into pinterest, goes to given site, and starts crawling the "previous post" links of the blog posts - pushes the "Pin it" button, selects the image, confirms (separate window) then jumps back to main window and starts another page.

As mentioned, I think its possible there is a "leak" somewhere causing it to grind to a hault after a while.

Comment: Which selenium and firefox versions are you using?

Comment: It appears to be selenium-2.39.0, and the latest firefox

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in multiple `sleep` calls - better use [selenium waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html), but, for starters, upgrade your selenium package to the latest version (2.43.* if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Will upgrading mean rewriting all my code? Noted on the 'wait' function

Comment: UPDATE: I changed to wait and updated, but now I have to do some rewriting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The title says the browser crashes whereas the body of the question says it "hangs" so which is it? There's a `print` statement in the Python code, does it continue to print while the browser appears unresponsive or does it stop? Any error message on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Per commenter's advice, simply changing every instance of:

```
time.sleep(3)
```

to

```
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

seems to have helped things. Also I updated to most recent version.

Comment: You just need to declare it once...and not needed to replace where ever "time.sleep(3)"